# Nancyfx localization

Tags: nancy

I'm testing localization in Nancy and able to get it to work using EMBEDDED resource files but the issue is I don't want embedded resource files because I want them to be allowed to be edited via the GUI or using the file (if I go the DB route or setting the resource file as "content").

According to the doucmentation you should be able to override it to support using a database but I'm unable to get this to work (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Localization):

```
public class ResourceManager : ResourceBasedTextResource
{
    public ResourceManager(IResourceAssemblyProvider resourceAssemblyProvider) : base(resourceAssemblyProvider)
    {

    }

    public new string this[string key, NancyContext context]
    {
        get
        {
            return "HELO!";
        }
    }
}
```

This was just me messing around but I was hoping in the Razor view when I did @Text.Localization. it should return "HELO!" for everything... however it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a question in your post so I'm going to have to guess a bit and assume that you're not getting any exception but rather you're not seeing the "HELO!" in your view

Simply implementing a new `ResourceBasedTextResource` class is not enough. This is a core component and as such you are going to explicitly have to tell Nancy to use it. You do this by overriding the `InternalConfiguration` property of your `Bootstrapper` and tell Nancy to use your implementation instead

You can see it in the `DemoBootstrapper` of the demo that is linked from that wiki page https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/8970ac9d6c7cf46e6060f0b83117c19fa18085c2/src/Nancy.Demo.Razor.Localization/DemoBootstrapper.cs#L11

Also, if you are not going to use resource files, then you should look into inheriting from [ITextResource](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Localization/ITextResource.cs) interface instead. It's a simple interface so it should be straight forward.

HTH